# how to update fragement data when swiching Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-recyclerview

I am using Material Tab that I used 3 tabs.

Tab A [ Product List ]

Has a Recycle list and data populating from remote Server. For ex, it has Product title, image and favorite image

Tab B [ Favorite Product List ]

Tab C [ Contact Us ]

What I try to implement, Once user select on favorite button ( add to favorite ) that particular list item show in TAB_B [ Favorite Product List ]

I have used shared preference and save data as Gson format. I have followed this tutorial

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/

The issue is, once I add Item and remove item from Product List [ Tab A ] perform well, and it is not showing at Tab B [ Favorite Product List ]. Once I restart the app Favorite Product List is showing at Tab b. I used some tricks like broadcast receivers kind of things but it is not working correctly.

I use `it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11` library to populate tabs

Here is my some codes that I have been used.

Please guide me, where I did wrong.

Comment: You can use EventBus for this. Or update list in ViewPager geItem(int position) adding public method to fragment

Comment: In all three tabs, are you using Fragments?

Comment: @Esperanz0 : Please can you give me an example. I bit new for that

Comment: @MahfuzIslamBhuiyan Yes for all 3 tabs I have 3 separate fragments

Answer (score 1):

1. add `compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0`' in gradle file
2. In every fragment add in onCreate()

   ```
           EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   ```
3. In every fragment add in onDestroyView

   ```
           EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
   ```
4. Create Java class for Event
   Example:

   ```
             public class EventUpdateList {

               private boolean listNeedUpdate= true;

               public EventUpdateList (boolean listNeedUpdate) {
                   this.listNeedUpdate= listNeedUpdate;
               }

               public boolean isListNeedUpdate() {
                   return listNeedUpdate;
               }

           }
   ```
5. In all fragments add

   ```
      @Subscribe(threadMode = Main)
       public void onListRefresh(EventUpdatelist eventUpdateList) 
       {
          if (eventUpdateList.isNeedListUpdate) 
       {
       // refresh your list

       }

       }
   ```
6. In your activity add

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault.post(new EventUpdateList(true));
   ```

And all 3 fragments getting information about event to refresh list.
You can even post Event with full list to refresh instead of this boolean and get in 3 fragments.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, I am so clear what you have told. I ll try this and will update whether its works or not.

Thank you very much for your valuable time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since the lib you're using basically uses ViewPager under the hood to manage given Fragment as Tab so this [setUserVisibleHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) method of Fragment should be the place you can update your tab content every time it loads.

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
              // Do stuffs that you want to do every time this fragment loads
        } else {
        }
}
```