# How to refresh listview in a tab from another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a tabbed activity with one of the tab has favorite movie recyclerView List. In another tab, all the movies will be shown and onclick of one movie will open the movie details Activity, where he can favorite that movie. I am only saving favorite movie's id in shared preferences. After he goes back to the favorite tab, I can fetch all the movies and display it, but for every new movie addition, fetching all the favorite items is not a good idea and maintaining the static variables for newly favorite movies and refreshing the list also not looking like a good idea.

I am thinking of using Interfaces,broadcast receiver or RxJava approach for this. But for interfaces, I can't hold the favorite tab instance in movie details activity all the time. Rxjava's Publish subject also good, but I need to maintain static reference to send event from movie details activity.

I am thinking the broadcast receivers or Rxjava approaches are the best way here. Please help me to pick the right implementation.

Comment: are you not saving favourite movies into server ?

Comment: there You have similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018098/how-to-update-fragement-data-when-swiching-tabs/39065983#39065983

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to specify setOffscreenPageLimit 0, so that when you are on the second page, the first one is destroyed, and vice-versa.

So, every time you tab your `listView` or `recylerView` load again.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Broadcast Intent from the previous fragment after you get the response in the next fragment make sure only the next fragment/tab is loaded you can also set data in the Activity also so if any change made in the data Fragment can incorporate it and **do not** override `destroyItem` this will 
help recreate fagment object again and you will get fresh data...problem will arise when

> you have to make changes from you next fragment to previous fragment!

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);
    Intent intent = new Intent("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", json.toString());
    intent.putExtra("bundle_key_for_intent", bundle);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and then you can receive the bundle in your fragment by using the BroadcastReceiver class

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new 
BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = 
            intent.getExtras().getBundle("bundle_key_for_intent");
            if(bundle!=null){
                String edttext = bundle.getString("edttext");
            }
            //you can call any of your methods for using this bundle for your use case
    }
};
```

in onCreateView() of your fragment you need to register the broadcast receiver first otherwise this broadcast receiver will not be triggered

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
getActivity().getApplicationContext().
               registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);
```

Finally you can unregister the receiver to avoid any exceptions

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {

         getActivity().getApplicationContext().
             unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

You can create separate broadcast receivers in all of your fragments and use the same broadcast to broadcast the data to all of your fragments. You can also use different keys for different fragments and then broadcast using particular key for particular fragment.